# Joined objects causes program to slow down in blender

Tags: blender

So I was just using blender 3D modelling and I decided to take 6 objects and join them together using CTRL + J and suddenly the program just slowed down real hard.

What is the cause of this please and is there a way to fix this? Do I have to delete my object again?

Comment: the blender stackexchange is a better place to ask this question. But from memory joining elements applies modifiers, including stuff like subdivision which can baloon your polygon count and slow down blender, especially in edit-mode.

Comment: ah ok thank you for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by applying the join modifier, applying it when needed, or upgrading your PC.

Comment: isn't join modifier same as pressing CTRL + J? correct me if I'm wrong. Also I really like to join objects together since it makes it much simpler to control the objects and also makes the workplace neater. I spent 1000 euros on upgrading my PC so I'm pretty sure that is not an issue since I have the latest tech but thank you for your input :)

Comment: CTRL + J is the shortcut for the join modifier, how many vertices were in the selection? I tried this on my laptop and noticed a slowdown at around 150,000 verts, although the slowdown was eliminated when I used wireframe mode. There are specialised GFX cards for CAD software that are much more efficient at drawing lines, assuming you aren't using regular GFX hardware.

Comment: I had over 40 million vertices and faces xD I use GTX 960

Comment: Like I said, I have a laptop. But to elaborate upon that, it's got an AMD A6-5200 APU, which starts to lag at 1 million verts. I should probably use layers or toggle visibility.